# How do I mock out Stripe network calls for testing in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, stripe-payments

I'm trying to test a function that's making a Stripe api call `Plan.retrieve("my_plan_id")`. I'm using junit as my testing library and mockito as my mocking library. The problem here is that `Plan.retrieve()` is a static method, and mockito doesn't support mocking static methods.

I've tried mocking out the `Plan` class like so.

```
Plan plan = new Plan();
plan.setId("my_plan_id");
Plan mockedPlan = mock(Plan.class);
when(mockedPlan.retrieve("my_plan_id")).thenReturn(plan);
assertEquals(plan.getId(), myTestedFunction().getId());
```

This just results in an Stripe Authentication exception because I never gave Stripe an API Key.

What is the correct implementation for mocking Stripe api calls for testing in java? I can't seem to find any information on this.

### Update

I was already aware of PowerMock, I was looking for a solution that involved using Mockito. Dawood ibn Kareem has pretty much answered my question. If I could mark that as the accepted answer I would. I admit that it was a pretty obvious answer, but for some reason it just didn't occur to me.

I also don't understand why people are downvoting my question, was it a bad question?

Comment: This object `Plan plan = new Plan()` is not a mock, thus it will execute its inner methods (if any). You should also mock that object as well.

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to wrap whichever part of the Stripe API you're using into your own wrapper class, without any static methods.  Then mock that.

Comment: Okay. That makes a ton of sense. I will try doing that.

Comment: I just read your update.  So what I described is basically 99Sono's answer to the question that fmatar linked to.  Instead of posting my answer here, it makes more sense to flag this as a duplicate.  I would recommend avoiding PowerMock if you possibly can.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I read that stackoverflow question when I did my initial research but I didn't scroll down enough to see 99Sono's answer. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: There is also another option if you want to get into the details of the Stripe implementation: you can implement `StripeResponseGetter` and call `ApiResource.setStripeResponseGetter(instance);`. This is the class that then gets called to perform any requests to Stripe. I am currently looking to see if something like `okhttp3.mock.MockInterceptor` from OkHTTP would be useful her to record and validate expectations. Might be more work than it is worth though.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito has no support for mocking static methods, you can use PowerMock to achieve the task. Specifically you should be looking at: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method

A similar question has been answered in this thread: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: seems that now Mockito suppports static methods mocking: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks .